# Function to return a associative array in php from another array

Tags: php, arrays

I am new in learning php and array .  I have to create an associative array from another array . In addition The array must be returned in alphabetical order based upon the key names.

this is the input array

```
        $customerTransactions = [
        'bill=9898',
        'bob=772',
        'james=2672',
        'jim=9872',
        'luke=2665',
        'jim=10000'
    ];
```

The output array should be like

```
$outputarray = [
            'bill' => 9898,
            'bob' => 772,
            'james' => 2672,
            'jim' => 19872,
            'luke' => 2665
        ],
```

I am trying to create  a function which will return the output array .

```
public function getCustomerBalances($customerTransactions)
{
      $max = sizeof($customerTransactions);     
      $str = implode(",", $customerTransactions);     

      $outputarray = print_r (explode("=",$str));

      return array($outputarray); 
}
```

But result of this array is this this

```
Array(
[0] => bill
[1] => 9898,bob
[2] => 772,james
[3] => 2672,jim
[4] => 9872,luke
[5] => 2665,jim
[6] => 10000)
```

What can I do to correct it

Comment: You need to `explode`, not `implode`, and not by a comma but by a `=`.

Comment: Explode works for string. As the input ($customerTransactions ) is an array and not string it gives error . for this reason I have converted the array into string first then again string to array.

Comment: The values in your array are strings, I'll post an answer in a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You want to use [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) not [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Below I have looped through your array of strings and `explode` each of the values in the array by the equals operator to get a new array that holds both the customer name and the transaction ID.

I am then populating a new array called `$data` with the results from this explosion, the first element in the `$result` array is the customer name, and the second element is the transaction ID.

---

Once you've got the array outputing correctly, you mentioned you wanted to order them alphabetically, to do this you would use [`ksort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php).

This is simple enough, you'd just need to call this function on the output array like so:

```
ksort($data);
```

---

**This should work for you:**

```
public function getCustomerBalances($transactions) {

    $data = [];

    foreach($transactions as $v) {
        $result = explode('=', $v);
        $data[$result[0]] = $result[1];
    }

    ksort($data);

    return $data; 

}
```

Comment: What is $result in here

Comment: If you explode `bill=9898` by `=` then it will become an array, so `$result` would be `['bill', '9898']`. So `$result[0]` is 'bill' and `$result[1]` is '9898'.